# Correct way to set up Jade with Yeoman/Grunt for templating

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, pug, yeoman

I am having difficulty getting the layouts and partials to play nice in my project and I was wondering what the correct way to set this up is.

I am using grunt-cotrib-jade

My file structure is like this:

```
app
  |_jade
  |     |_layouts
  |     |      |_ _default_layout.jade
  |     |      |_ _layout.jade
  |     |
  |     |_partials
  |     |      |_ _html-head.jade
  |     |      |_ _head.jade
  |     |      |_ _foot.jade
  |     |
  |     |_Page-1
  |     |      |_index.jade
  |     |      |_partials
  |     |
  |     |_Page-2
  |     |      |_partials
  |     |      |_index.jade
  |     |
  |     |_index.jade
  |
  |_sass
  |_scripts
  |_images
  |_bower_components
```

So far I have got grunt compiling everything except the use of layouts and partials is not working. I have problems when I have scripts etc in `_head.jade` or `_foot.jade` and then on `page-1/index.jade` I call the layout using `extends ../layouts/_default_layout`. The _default_layout.jade looks like this:

```
!!! 5
//if lt IE 7
  html.no-js.lt-ie9.lt-ie8.lt-ie7  
//if IE 7
  html.no-js.lt-ie9.lt-ie8  
//if IE 8
  html.no-js.lt-ie9  
// [if gt IE 8] <!
html.no-js
  // <![endif]

  include ../partials/_html-head

  body(class=page)
    include ../partials/_head
    block content
    include ../partials/_foot
```

And finally I have put my `Gruntfile.js` up here http://jsfiddle.net/daimz/G7vYP/1/

If anyone has any advice on how to structure and set this up properly I would be really grateful as I really want to be able to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 0):

you called the include by `header` and `footer` but your files are named `head.jade` and `foot.jade` They have to match

Comment: I made a typo when creating this question. Sorry about the confusion. In practise they are using the same name. Basically the biggest issue is I can see the content that is being included but all scripts and styles that are in those includes don't match. main.css should be at localhost:8000/css/main.css but when I check console it is looking for it at localhost:8000/page-1/css/main.css so this is why I think I have done things wrong as I don't imagine partials and layouts should work like this.